# Filtering an array in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I have an array of integers where I'm treating 0 in a special way.  I need to manipulate the array so that the output is an array of the same size with all the zeros after all the non-zero values.  For example:

```ocaml
input:  [| 10; 5; 4; 0; 6; 0; 0; 0; 0 |]
output: [| 10; 5; 4; 6; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0 |]
```

This is some code I got to work:

```ocaml
let a = [| 10; 5; 4; 0; 6; 0; 0; 0; 0 |] in
let l = List.filter (fun c -> c <> 0) (Array.to_list a) in
let cells i = if i <= List.length l - 1 then List.nth l i else 0 in
Array.init (Array.length a) cells;;
```

I have a feeling that this solution could be improved by addressing:

1. converting back and forth between lists and arrays.  Is there a better way than calling `Array.to_list` and then `List.filter` to keep the order and exclude certain values?
2. accessing a list using `List.nth` which is O(i) for each position in the array.  Is there a better way to use a list's values as the first source when populating an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right that the `List.nth` in this code will cause it to be slow for large arrays.

You could construct the result as a list just by appending the right number of 0s to it. Then you could use `Array.of_list` to get the final array. That would avoid the quadratic cost of the repeated calls to `List.nth`.

You could also construct your result as an array directly without using lists at all.

Something like this:

```
let compress ar =
    let res = Array.make (Array.length ar) 0 in
    let c ix ari =
        if ari = 0 then ix
        else (res.(ix) <- ari; ix + 1)
    in
    let _ = Array.fold_left c 0 ar in
    res
```

This isn't pure code; i.e., it modifies the result array. That's kind of a drag. But arrays in OCaml are mutable after all.

Here is how it works on your test data:

```
# compress [| 10; 5; 4; 0; 6; 0; 0; 0; 0 |];;
- : int array = [|10; 5; 4; 6; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0|]
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

You could also use Array's fold_left...

```
let sort_arr a =
  let len = Array.length a in
  let pos = ref 0 in
  let sort_arr_aux p a =
    Array.fold_left
      (
        fun a d ->
          if d > 0
          then
            (
              Array.set a (!pos) d;
              pos := !pos + 1
            );
          a
      ) (Array.make len 0) a in
  sort_arr_aux pos a
```

Answer (score 1):

As another alternative, simply leverage `Array.sort`, using the comparator function to shunt zeroes to the end of the array.

```
utop # let arr = [| 10; 5; 4; 0; 6; 0; 0; 0; 0 |] in
Array.sort 
  (fun a b -> 
     if a = 0 then 1 
     else if b = 0 then -1 
     else 0) 
  arr;
arr;;
- : int array = [|10; 5; 4; 6; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0|]
```